# Rails joins query killed or just too slow. Please recommend the proper way to create queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble properly creating query with joins. It starts to talk to server but it ends up clogged and saying "killed" (in Rails console)

I have to models.

One is 'User', the other one is 'Availability'

Some users will open availabilities in 2 weeks. And I'd like to fetch 50 users with this condition with page variable.(because there will be many of them and I'd like to fetch 50 on every call)

Availability has two columns: user_id and start_time(datetime)

And the association is that user has many availabilities.

The query looks like the below.

```
people = User
 .where(role: SOMETHING)
 .includes(:availabilities)
 .joins(:availabilities)
 .where('availabilities.start_time > ?', Time.now)
 .where('availabilities.start_time < ?', Time.now + 2.weeks)
 .limit(5)
 .offset(50 * (n-1))
```

where n is integer from 1

However, this query never gives me result on the production (in the console it's killed. Before the console kills the process, when querying, it shows normal query statement (sql 30ms for instance) forever. In local, where data is small, it works. Are there anything missing here?

Please give me any advice!!

And weird thing is ,

```
people = User
     .where(role: SOMETHING)
     .includes(:availabilities)
     .joins(:availabilities)
     .limit(5)
     .offset(50 * (n-1))
```

then if

people.map(&:id) => [18,18,18,18,18]

which means people is inappropriately fetched. I am just confused here..!

Comment: use either joins or includes.

Comment: Check your memory usage. I'm fairly sure the message "Killed" comes from the OS when you have run out of memory.

Comment: @muistooshort hi, would you mind give me some guidance how to use indexes? I'm quite new to this.! And what does that mean that Limit/offset paging can get really expensive with large result sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes availabilities will generate availability model instances after querying.

If availability rows are so many, it will cost a lot of time.

If you won't use availabilities after querying, please try

```rb
people = User
 .where(role: ROLES)
 .joins(:availabilities)
 .where(availabilities: {start_time: (Time.now)..(2.weeks.from_now)})
 .offset(50 * (n-1))
 .limit(5)
```

Comment: Hi @adam, it is weird that same users are fetched to people. For instance, people.map(&:id) =>[18,18,18,18,18]. Do you know where I'm bogged down now?

Comment: Yeah.You got it.Use scope method distinct.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of find the way to work it:

```
people = User
  .where(role: ROLES)
  .joins(:availabilities)
  .where(availabilities: { start_time: (Time.now)..(2.weeks.from_now) })
  .distinct
  .offset(50 * (n-1))
  .limit(5)
```

Then:

```
people.map(&:id), => [x,y,z,l,m]
```